# How to bypass getIntent() and getStringExtra() when running MainActivity for the first time

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am having an issue where the following code is causing my app to crash.

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
Intent intent = getIntent();
final String years = intent.getStringExtra(MenuActivity.yearsMessage);
final String rate = intent.getStringExtra(MenuActivity.rateMessage);
```

If it is the first time opening my app, the blank values that come from the getStringExtra() commands cause the app to crash when they are called later in the code.

```
double rate = Double.parseDouble(rateString);
double years = Double.parseDouble(yearsString);
double outFloat = inFloat * Math.pow((1f + rate), years);
return df2.format(outFloat);
```

Does anyone know a way that I can declare the default values for the getStringExtra method when it is the first time opening the App?

Comment: Check the values for `null`, then use the default values.

Comment: As above - You should never assume the "happy path" in programming ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try checking for null values on the variables years and rate, as CommonsWare said and it might also be a good idea to put the parses inside a try catch, just in case that the parse fails

```
if (years != null && rate != null) {
    try {
        double rate = Double.parseDouble(rateString);
        double years = Double.parseDouble(yearsString);
        double outFloat = inFloat * Math.pow((1f + rate), years);
        return df2.format(outFloat);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: This fixed my issue! Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You can check when there is an extra available,  try this way:

```
if (intent.hasExtra("years") && intent.hasExtra("rate")){
  final String years = intent.getStringExtra("years");
  final String rate = intent.getStringExtra("rate");
}
```

[Intent - hasExtra](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#hasExtra(java.lang.String))

Don't forget that you have to send the data using key/value parameter in your intent, like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,YourActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("years", yearsMessage);
intent.putEtra("rate", ratesMessage);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

I thinkYour syntax for receiving the strings from the other activity is faulty. Replace the menuactivity.yearsmessage with a key that you assigned in the putExtra on the sending activity

Comment: `MenuActivity.yearsmessage` could well be the key - no code provided for the storing, so you can't assume this.